# django templating system inheritance issue

Tags: python, django, inheritance, templates

i am having issues with my django templating system, i have a base.html file, which contains the content which will be common on all the web pages of the web site, the base.html file fetches some dynamic content, like the categories and the archives, which are passed to it by a python file, which fetches the categories and the archives data from a mysql database.

the issue when i inherit this base.html file in other html files like index.html:

{% extends "base.html" %}

and when when i call the main index URL for ex: http://mywebsite.com/index/

the index page gets loaded, but the categories and the archives data that should get loaded from the base.html file does not.

what am i doing wrong, please help.

Comment: How does the base.html file fetch dynamic content? Using template tags? Or is it passed in as context when the template is rendered?

Comment: A little bit more info, e.g. provide a sample base.html and derived.html that reproduces the problem. Further: if you look at the source, do you miss the data or the whole html structure of base.html?

Comment: i'll provide a small code from my base.html file:                                                                                                                                        {% if categories %}

     <span class="sidebar-list">

     <h4>Categories</h4>

     <p class="title-seperator"></p>

      <ul>   

      {% for objectcategory in categories %}

      <li><a href="{{objectcategory.url}}">{{objectcategory.category}}</a></li>

   {% endfor %}

Comment: Where is the {% categories %} variable created originally?

Comment: and then passed to the template as context?

Can you paste in the code in your views.py?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have one (or both) of these issues:

1. The block in base.html is being overridden with a block in the index.html, and you haven't used `{{block.super}}` to include the content from the base template.
2. The view function that invokes index.html isn't creating the proper context variables to give the template the data it needs.

Comment: no, that didn't help, the issue is, there is a simple line below the code i have posted above   <img src="http://mywebsite.com/media/cellpassion/images/adv-sony.jpg" /></a>
<img src="http://mywebsite.com/media/cellpassion/images/adv-LG.jpg" />

both these lines are in the base.html file and they are getting loaded, but the code above that is the data that should loaded the categories, is not getting loaded.

i am really tired, trying to solve the issue from past 2 days.

Comment: Suhail, you're going to have to post more code, then.  The problem is probably simple, but we don't have enough information.

Comment: can i mail you the python and the html files ?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just paste code here?  If it is too large, then perhaps you need to whittle it down anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As this is an old issue, it's probably been resolved by now, but I found an issue with Django 1.1 where template inheritance doesn't seem to work in certain situations.

My app is called 'budget'. Templates are in PROJECTROOT/budget/templates/budget, and I've defined my template directory as PROJECTROOT/budget/templates.

Inside the templates/budget directory I have base.html and index.html. index.html extends base.html via 'extends "budget/base.html"'.

When I hit the index url, the index.html template renders without inheriting from base.html. When I switched the naming of index.html to budget_index.html, everything worked as expected.

I hope this helps somebody, as I've been bashing my head against this for a few hours now.